Wiremock could not find helper: 'jwt' {{{jwt maxAge='12 days'}}}
I tried to use the jwt in JSON tag as declared in wiremock documentation with no luck.
thing.json
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/some/thing"
  },

  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "{{{jwt maxAge='12 days'}}}",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
    }
  }
}


Here is the error I got:
Error 500 wiremock.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException:
  wiremock.com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: inline@15b3ed:1:3:
  could not find helper:
        &apos;jwt&apos;
        {{{jwt maxAge=&apos;12 days&apos;}}}
        ^

which translates to could not find helper'jwt' {{{jwt maxAge='12 days'}}}.

To be able to use JWT in JSON as declared here. Some configuration needs to be done.
JWT extension
Is the way to enable the JWT helper for Wiremock.
An extension package should be added in the var/wiremock/extensions directory. This can be done using docker mapping.
The extension wiremock-jwt-extension-standalone-x.y.z.jar is created by Wiremock and available here.
The wiremock server will auto detect the extensions at the startup.
Files hierarchy
├── docker-compose.yml
├── extensions
│   └── wiremock-jwt-extension-standalone-0.1.0.jar
├── __files
├── mappings
│   └── v1
│       └── thing.json

Docker Compose
version: "3"
services:
  wiremock:
    image: "wiremock/wiremock:latest"
    container_name: my_wiremock
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./extensions:/var/wiremock/extensions
      - ./__files:/home/wiremock/__files
      - ./mappings:/home/wiremock/mappings
    entrypoint: ["/docker-entrypoint.sh", "--global-response-templating",
                 "--disable-gzip", "--verbose"]

Note
Make sure --global-response-templating option is set at the wiremock server startup.
Links
GitHub repo: wiremock-jwt-extension.
The maven repo: wiremock-jwt-extension-standalone.
Docker Hub repo: wiremock.
The used package name is wiremock-jwt-extension-standalone not wiremock-jwt-extension.

You also have the option of adding the response-template transformer to individual stubs rather than enabling global response templating, which makes sense if you only want a few stubs to be templated.
